# Inspector : Display editable member that’s inside member

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a class that is a monobehaviour called InventorySlot. 
It has a member that is of normal class Item. 
Item has a field int Amount.

Is it possible to make a custom inspector that lets me see and modify the amount of item when I inspect InventorySlot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make a custom editors in Unity. See here: [CustomEditors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html)

You may not need an editor for what you're trying to achieve however. It sounds like your `Item` class (and/or `Amount` field) isn't serialiazed. You can add a `Serializable` attribute (See [Serializable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serializable.html)) to your `Item` class and make your `Amount` field public to resolve this.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public int Amount;
}
```